# Finding text in other text field

Tags: java, parsing, text

I have a question about parsing text in Java.

```
  Name  Virtual address  Virtual size  Raw size  Entropy  MD5
  CODE  4096  37732  37888  6.56  2c410dfc3efd04d9b69c35c70921424e
  DATA  45056  588  1024  2.74  d5ea23d4ecf110fd2591314cbaa84278
  BSS  49152  3720  0  0.00  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
 .idata  53248  2384  2560  4.43  bb5485bf968b970e5ea81292af2acdba
 .tls  57344  8  0  0.00  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
 .rdata  61440  24  512  0.20  9ba824905bf9c7922b6fc87a38b74366
 .reloc  65536  2228  0  0.00  d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
 .rsrc  69632  378360  378368  4.42  dc75e95cd49ce06a635cad0b18dab6d7
 ? Runtime DLLs
 c:\docume~1\<USER>~1\locals~1\temp\glc1.tmp (successful)
 c:\docume~1\<USER>~1\locals~1\temp\glk2.tmp (successful)
 riched32.dll (successful)
 secur32.dll (successful)
 shell32.dll (successful)
 ole32.dll (successful)
 setupapi.dll (successful)
 rpcrt4.dll (successful)
 clbcatq.dll (successful)
 comctl32.dll (successful)
 ntshrui.dll (successful)
 linkinfo.dll (successful)
 userenv.dll (successful)
 netapi32 (successful)
 Contract
 ? PE imports
 [+] advapi32.dll ()
 LookupPrivilegeValueA
```

I want to parse text, which is in section Runtime DLLS. Is any solution, which start append to stringbuilder, when it find string Runtime DLLS and it will appending while it find next? Which is i a row with PE IMPORTS? Or will they choose other solution for this parsing?

Answer (score 1):

You can read text file line by line and start appending lines to stringbuilder after finding string "Runtime DLLs" until find finish line:

```
String file = "your_file";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
boolean flag = false;
try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        if (line.trim().startsWith("? ")) { //lines starting at "? "
            flag = !flag;
            continue;
        }

        if (flag) {
            //here lines can be parsed to successful or not
            result.append(line + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But there are many textfields, and not in every follow PE Imports after DLLS...for this need i find solution..thanks

Comment: I updated my snippet: it find all string starting at "? " and include to stringbuilder content inside pair of "? ".

Comment: It will so good that it will start append on value which i want and stop at next ? in a row..how to do it so?

Comment: It would be better to have a pattern for this strings like string starting at 
question mark. Do you want to point list of "start" and "end" strings?

Comment: if it will be best solution..okey..how to?